# How to insert a hubspot form in a react js app?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, hubspot

i have a react js website and i want to insert a hubspot form.

Hubspot form:

```
<script charset="utf-8" type="text/javascript" src="//js-eu1.hsforms.net/forms/shell.js"></script>
<script>
  hbspt.forms.create({
    region: "eu1",
    portalId: "25082527",
    formId: "8a7c2adb-5c41-4c47-8478-b1f1abe01e3f"
});
</script>
```

react js page contact

```
import React from 'react';
import SEO from "../common/SEO";
import Layout from "../common/Layout";
import ContactOne from "../elements/contact/ContactOne";

const ContactPage = () => {
    return (
        <>
            <SEO title="Contact" desc="EXIGOH - Contact us now"/>
            <Layout>
                <div className="main-content">
                    {/* Start Contact Area  */}
                    <div className="rwt-contact-area rn-section-gap">


                        <div className="container">
                            <div className="row">
                                <div className="col-lg-12 mb--40">
                                    <div className="text-center">
                                        <h1 className="title theme-gradient h2" dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{__html: 'The Easiest Way To Start <br /> fill in & send.'}}/>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            
                            **<<<<<<<< -------------- insert it here >>** 

                            {/*<ContactOne/>*/}
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    {/* End Contact Area  */}
                </div>
            </Layout>
        </>
    )
}
export default ContactPage;
```

so my question is: how can i do that? i tried  to use `<helmet>` but this don't work for me. how can i insert script tags in react js?

Comment: I have the same issue, please keep me posted.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here's what I did, worked like a charm...

1. create a Component called `HubspotContactForm`

```js
    import React, {useEffect} from "react";
    
    const HubspotContactForm = props => {
        const { region, portalId, formId } = props;
        useEffect(() => {
            const script = document.createElement('script');
            script.src='https://js.hsforms.net/forms/shell.js';
            document.body.appendChild(script);
    
            script.addEventListener('load', () => {
                // @TS-ignore
                if (window.hbspt) {
                    // @TS-ignore
                    window.hbspt.forms.create({
                        region: region,
                        portalId: portalId,
                        formId: formId,
                        target: '#hubspotForm'
                    })
                }
            });
        }, []);
    
        return (
            <div>
                <div id="hubspotForm"></div>
            </div>
        );
    };
    
    export default HubspotContactForm;
```

2. import this component and use it on a page:

```js
import {
  HubspotContactForm,
} from '../components';

export default function MyPage() {
  return (
    <main>
      <div className="container">
        <div className="row">
          <div className="col">
                <HubspotContactForm 
                region="na1"
                portalId="12345678"
                formId='4333d218-20e3-41f9-a478-47bd0c26bf1a'
                />
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>  
     </main>
  );
};
```

Comment: idk why it not working when i used function component as given above, as i switch to class based it works. any reason ?

Comment: There are a few ways to do this depending upon how you project is structured

Comment: Worked like a charm, thank you. Anyways, slightly out of context, but have you been able to validate the user input data of the Hubspot form?

Comment: Thanks, the Hubspot contact form has its own built in field validation for types etc is this what you meant?

Answer (score 1):

Somehow the functional component solution posted by @jeffreyaven didn't work (the target div remained unchanged even though JS got executed).

The solution that worked for me was based on a class component:

```js
import React from "react";

class HubspotContactForm extends React.Component<{
  portalId: string;
  formId: string;
  region: string;
}> {
  componentDidMount() {
    const script = document.createElement("script");
    script.src = "https://js.hsforms.net/forms/v2.js";
    document.body.appendChild(script);

    script.addEventListener("load", () => {
      // @ts-ignore
      if (window.hbspt) {
        // @ts-ignore
        window.hbspt.forms.create({
          target: "#hubspotForm",
          ...this.props,
        });
      }
    });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <div id="hubspotForm" />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default HubspotContactForm;
```

this component can be used in exactly the same way:

```js
import {
  HubspotContactForm,
} from '../components';

export default function MyPage() {
  return (
    <main>
      <div className="container">
        <div className="row">
          <div className="col">
                <HubspotContactForm 
                region="na1"
                portalId="12345678"
                formId='4333d218-20e3-41f9-a478-47bd0c26bf1a'
                />
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>  
     </main>
  );
};
```

[JSFiddle example](https://jsfiddle.net/2Lwq9zbg/)

[Source](https://community.hubspot.com/t5/APIs-Integrations/HELP-Embed-a-form-in-a-React-component/m-p/230049/highlight/true#M8945)

Answer (score 1):

I tried jeffreyaven reply but the form wasn't showing. I removed the destructured props and it worked:

```
import React, { useEffect } from 'react'

const HubspotContactForm = (props) => {
  useEffect(() => {
    const script = document.createElement('script')
    script.src = 'https://js-eu1.hsforms.net/forms/embed/v2.js'
    document.body.appendChild(script)

    script.addEventListener('load', () => {
      if (window.hbspt) {
        window.hbspt.forms.create({
          target: '#hubspotForm',
          ...props
        })
      }
    })
  }, [])

  return <div id="hubspotForm"></div>
}

export default HubspotContactForm
```